# How to create Sub matrix(all 5*5) from a Matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, matlab-compiler

How to create Sub matrix(all 5*5) from a Matrix in MATLAB? This can be done by shifting exactly one row and one column.I have tried with following code but i'm not getting the actual output.Here A is the input matrix.

```
A=[40 45 50 60 70 80; 
    10 12 15 17 18 20; 
    35 41 57 44 98 78;
    45 74 11 2 36 78;
    12 45 79 85 36 45; 
    1 5 8 78 47 3]

for i=1:size(A,1)-4   
       for j=1:size(A,2)-4      
          B{i,j}=A(i:i+4,j:j+4)        
       end 
     end
```

Now i,m getting this output:

```
A =

   40   45   50   60   70   80
   10   12   15   17   18   20
   35   41   57   44   98   78
   45   74   11    2   36   78
   12   45   79   85   36   45
    1    5    8   78   47    3

B = 
{
  [1,1] =

     40   45   50   60   70
     10   12   15   17   18
     35   41   57   44   98
     45   74   11    2   36
     12   45   79   85   36

}
B = 
{
  [1,1] =

     40   45   50   60   70
     10   12   15   17   18
     35   41   57   44   98
     45   74   11    2   36
     12   45   79   85   36

  [1,2] =

     45   50   60   70   80
     12   15   17   18   20
     41   57   44   98   78
     74   11    2   36   78
     45   79   85   36   45

}
B = 
{
  [1,1] =

     40   45   50   60   70
     10   12   15   17   18
     35   41   57   44   98
     45   74   11    2   36
     12   45   79   85   36

  [2,1] =

     10   12   15   17   18
     35   41   57   44   98
     45   74   11    2   36
     12   45   79   85   36
      1    5    8   78   47

  [1,2] =

     45   50   60   70   80
     12   15   17   18   20
     41   57   44   98   78
     74   11    2   36   78
     45   79   85   36   45

  [2,2] = [](0x0)
}
B = 
{
  [1,1] =

     40   45   50   60   70
     10   12   15   17   18
     35   41   57   44   98
     45   74   11    2   36
     12   45   79   85   36

  [2,1] =

     10   12   15   17   18
     35   41   57   44   98
     45   74   11    2   36
     12   45   79   85   36
      1    5    8   78   47

  [1,2] =

     45   50   60   70   80
     12   15   17   18   20
     41   57   44   98   78
     74   11    2   36   78
     45   79   85   36   45

  [2,2] =

     12   15   17   18   20
     41   57   44   98   78
     74   11    2   36   78
     45   79   85   36   45
      5    8   78   47    3

}
```

But I need the output look like this:

```
40   45   50   60   70
10   12   15   17   18
35   41   57   44   98
45   74   11    2   36
12   45   79   85   36


45   50   60   70   80
12   15   17   18   20
41   57   44   98   78
74   11    2   36   78
45   79   85   36   45

10   12   15   17   18
35   41   57   44   98
45   74   11    2   36
12   45   79   85   36
1    5    8   78   47


12   15   17   18   20
41   57   44   98   78
74   11    2   36   78
45   79   85   36   45
5    8   78   47    3
```

What i have to change in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've created a cell array of matrices, hence why `B` is shown as it is.

Try doing this:

```
A=[40 45 50 60 70 80; 
   10 12 15 17 18 20; 
   35 41 57 44 98 78;
   45 74 11 2 36 78;
   12 45 79 85 36 45; 
   1 5 8 78 47 3];

for i=1:size(A,1)-4   
   for j=1:size(A,2)-4      
      B = A(i:i+4,j:j+4);
      disp(B)        
   end 
 end
```

Depending on what you want to do with each submatrix, what to do next will differ. One approach you could take would be saving the submatrix on a .mat file with a related name such as:

```
save(['B_',num2str(i),'_',num2str(j),'.mat'],'B')
```

(put this line where `disp` is called in my example.)

Comment: This is the Error i'm getting.Error using
save
Unable to write
file B_1_1.mat:
permission
denied.

Error in
newtesting
(line 9)
        save(['B_',num2str(i),'_',num2str(j),'.mat'],'B') 
newtesting
Error using
save
Unable to write
file B_1_1.mat:
permission
denied.

Error in
newtesting
(line 9)
        save(['B_',num2str(i),'_',num2str(j),'.mat'],'B')

Comment: Odd. Are you working on a folder where you have write permissions? Try saving in a different place of maybe with a different name such as C_1_1.mat. Meanwhile, did the B matrices appear on console as you wanted?

Comment: Yes,B matrices is appearing in the console.But that error is there. Another thing is that how can i use all this 5*5 matrices ? Because i have to update all the matrices value using a formula.Then all the updated 5*5 matrices should be save in another variable.

Comment: As a quickfix, the dreaded eval function comes to mind. eval('B_',num2str(i),'_',num2str(j),'= B;') should attibute each value of B to variables named B_1_1 and so on. Then you'd have them all at your workspace.

Comment: @ArijitPanigrahi : I've tried just now to reproduce your error, but it didn't occur to me. Is the error solved for you? Did you have to do any fix?

Comment: did you try eval('B_',num2str(i),'_',num2str(j),'= B;')  instead of saving the files?

Answer (score 1):

The repeated display is due to the missing semi-colon in the line where you're saving the sub-matrices in `B`. 
The output you're expecting needs this indexing:

```
B{j,i} = A(i:i+4, j:j+4);
```

and then you may use `celldisp(B)` to display the cells.

Please also pre-allocate the cell-array before the loop with `B=cell(2, 2);`